# Algorithm for the inversion of a striped matrix with tridiagonal stripes

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, matrices, linear-algebra

I'd like to compute the inverse of a matrix of size $S^2N \times S^2N$ over complex numbers that is composed of tri-diagonal $S\times S$ size blocks of tri-diagonal $S\times S$ block matrices. This leads to a matrix with tri-diagonal stripes.

I know that there exist algorithms with speed-ups for tri-diagonal matrices and [striped matrices](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2005.02.012). However the striped ones assumes that the stripes are 'thin', i.e separated by at least one line of 0's. This assumption is based on the fact that the inverse of a banded matrix may not be banded. However, given that in the tri-diagonal case there exist fast-algorithms I am motivated to ask the question:

Are there ways to use the structure of the matrix, that I described, to speed up the matrix inversion? What if there is additional structure like the matrix and all the blocks and block of blocks being hermitian? Since I'm considering very large matrices approximate methods are also welcome.

Comment: Do you want to compute the inverse, or do you want to solve the linear system? These two questions are very different. If the latter, this is one of the classic algorithms, implemented in FISHPACK. https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0714048

Comment: The quantity I need is a sum over all entries of a matrix $X$ given by $AX = B$ (all matrices, B is diagonal) so I do need the inverse.

Comment: Why not delete and repost at Math SE?

Comment: I realized that the grand sum of $X$ can be computed by a linear system. But @Pseudonym the problem is not block tri-diagonal, but striped with tri-diagonals. I'll leave this question to be about the inverse and make a new one for the linear equation.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo [scicomp.SE] will probably get better answers than Math SE.